# Derivative function went wrong

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to take the derivative of this function but I am facing some difficulties.

$$f(x)= e^{\ln(e^{7x^2+11})}$$

My answer was : $7e^{(7(x^2))}*14x$
 I cancelled the $\ln$ with the $e$ first, then I downgrade the $7$ and keep the $\exp$. as it is, after that I took the derivative of the $7x^2$ and the result was the one on top.

Comment: I have added LaTeX formatting to your post, please verify that the formatting is correct and what you intended.

Comment: Note that there are (and were before the editing) $4$ left parentheses and $3$ right parentheses. It would be useful to know exactly what function is being differentiated.

Comment: What was the result of your cancellation?  (I suspect the missing right parenthesis would say that the argument of $\ln$ is $e^{7x^2}$ and not $e^{7x^2}+11$...)

Comment: @gekkostate How to do the LaTeX formatting ? and no it is wrong, the 11 is an exponent of the ln(e) also

Comment: Do you mean to say $f(x) = e^{(\ln(e^{(7(x^2))}+11)}$?  Because the problem as written says  $f'(x) = e^{(\ln(e^{(7(x^2))}+11)}$.  Also, there are and *odd* number (that number being $7$) of parentheses, going against the grain of the usual rule that they occur in pairs.

Comment: @RobertLewis it has been fixed

Comment: @user157908 Can you change $f′(x)$ to $f(x)$?

Comment: @mike I did, thanks for notifying me

Comment: @user157908:  thanks for the corrections; I see they got you your answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the derivative of the following function

$$f(x)= e^{ln(e^{7x^2+11})}$$

then your first step would be correct. The $e$ and the $\ln$ "cancel" each other out and you are left with

$$e^{7x^2+11}$$

Now, this is a classic case for the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) which states

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Suppose our function is $z = e^{7x^2+11}$ and we want to find the derivative with respect to $x$ but our function is a composite function so we let the composite part equal $y$ which would be $y = 7x^2 + 11$. Now, we use the chain rule so we have

\begin{align}
\frac{dz}{dx} &= \frac{dz}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \\
\frac{dz}{dx} &= \frac{d}{dy} e^y \cdot \frac{d}{dx}7x^2+11 \\
&= e^y \cdot 14x \\
&= e^{7x^2+11} \cdot 14x
\end{align}

So, our answer is $e^{7x^2+11} \cdot 14x$. I feel that you are making an error when you talk about downgrading the $7$, I don't quite understand why you would need to do that. If you have any further questions then please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)= e^{\ln(e^{7x^2+11})}=\exp(\ln(\exp(7x^2+11)))$$

So

$$f(x)= \exp(7x^2+11), \implies f'(x)=14x\exp(7x^2+11)$$